# Unit Testing Sqoop Applications

Tags: unit-testing, sqoop

I am using SQOOP as a technology to download lots of data from mysql to HDFS. sometimes, I need to write some special queries in sqoop to download the data.

One of the problems I feel with sqoop is that its virtually untestable. There is absolutely no guidance or technology to unit test a sqoop.

If anyone is using sqoop for data integration. How do you test your sqoop applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaif as of now there is no unit testing frameworks for sqoop, you can follow below approach

1) schedule a sqoop eval job , that will have source query to display output of source table.

```
$ sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://db.example.com/corp \
        --query "SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT 10"
```

2) Run the corresponding hive query or hdfs shell command to get the data or count after sqoop is completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use free-form queries via `--query`, you can use built-in `--validate` option to match records count in source table and HDFS. Unfortunately it will fail on big tables in MS SQL (record count>int capacity) because Sqoop is not aware of `count_big()`.